# Getting subdocuments of a mongodb document where the subdocument exists in different collection

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I have two collections in my mongodb or two schemas in mongoose - Users and Accounts. 
The User Schema

```
{
  account: [{type: db.Schema.Types.ObjectId , ref: 'Account'}]
}
```

The Account Schema looks like below.

```
{network:String,
 firstName: String,
 lastName:String,
 networkId:Number,
 accessToken: String,
 accessTokenExpiration:Number,
 userId: {type: db.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
}
```

So it is basically a 1-many relationship between Users and Accounts. In express I have a route to get the details of the user say /api/user with parameters userId (matches the mongodb objectId for User). 
I would like to return the entire user object for this request. It should contain the subdocuments as well (i.e. all the user accounts).

e.g.

```
{ "_id": "51e1b1b2993a51b0ce000005", "account": [ {
"network": "Facebook",
"networkId": xxxx,
"accessToken": "yyyyy",
"accessTokenExpiration": 11111,
"firstName": "John",
"lastName":"Doe"
} ] }
```

rather than

```
{ "_id": "51e1b1b2993a51b0ce000005", "account": [ "51e1b1b2993a51b0ce000004" ] }
```

Is there a mongodb or mongoose way to this without actually having to iterate the account array in the User object and search in the accounts collection.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose have [population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) designed especially for this case:

```
Users.findById(id)
  .populate('account')
  .exec(function (err, user) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(user);
  })
```

Or, if you're using [express-mongoose](https://github.com/LearnBoost/express-mongoose) plugin:

```
res.send(Users.findById(id).populate('account'))
```